# How to get CGPoint where a gesture is happening in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have added a gesture recognizer because I want to get the x coordinate of a touch (working on an audio trimmer, so I need the x coordinate for the handles of the trimmer).

I have

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
CGPoint leftControlPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"this is where the touch is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(leftControlPoint));
```

However, the NSLog simply gives me {0,0}.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks what I can do?

Comment: Um, `recognizer` is `nil` in the code you posted.  And you're using the base class.  You probably want a derived class, like `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`.  So, it's not clear what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to wire up a gesture recognizer is something like this:

```
// In some method, probably -viewDidLoad:

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(didTapView:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then:

```
- (void)didTapView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint leftControlPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"this is where the touch is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(leftControlPoint));
}
```